# Check internet connection in Android WebView (Cordova)

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, webview

I know there is a lot of questions and answers about this in `Stackoverflow`, I read a lot of them, but none of them work.

I clarified in the title Android `WebView` because it is the most important target, but I would like this works in other devices too. I tested the following code on a ***app built with `Intel XDK` installed on a `SM-G355M` with `Android 4.4.2`*** and on **`Safari` installed on an `iPhone 5C` with `iOS 9.3.4`**;

All I get in both cases is the same value, `true` (sometimes I get `false` even I have an internet connection).

I tried:

1. `navigator.onLine`, it gives always the same value.
2. `document.addEventListener("online", ...` doesn't trigger
3. `ajax` doesn't work, anyway **doesn't affect to the server?**

**Code:** https://nanilab.com/stackoverflow/webview-internet-connection.php(This link is now broken)

---

**Option 1**:

```
function option1(){
    var isOffline = 'onLine' in navigator && !navigator.onLine,
        text = isOffline == true ? ' without connection ' : ' connected ';

    $('.option-one span').text(text);
    $('.option-one i').text('checked').hide().fadeIn(200);

    setTimeout(function(){
        option1();
    }, 1000);
}
```

**Option 2**:

```
window.addEventListener("offline", function(){ $('.option-two span').text(' without connection'); }, false);
window.addEventListener("online", function(){ $('.option-two span').text(' connected'); }, false);
```

**Option 3**:

```
function option3(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/stackoverflow/blank.php',
        success: function(data){
            print(' connected ');
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
            print(' without connection ');
        }
    }); 

    function print(text){
        $('.option-three span').text(text);
        $('.option-three i').text('checked').hide().fadeIn(200);

        setTimeout(function(){
            option3();
        }, 2000);
    }
}
```

---

**app built with `Intel XDK` installed on a `SM-G355M with Android 4.4.2`**

https://youtu.be/wHJHG5dP_eM

---

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information

Comment: @HarishKommuri Thanks, but I want to make it work in mobile browsers too. Is there something general?

Comment: The Network Information API that the plugin depends on also works on Chrome 48+, while I'm not sure they are 100% compatible. https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/network-information/index.html

Comment: How is this related to Cordova?

Comment: @daserge "app built with Intel XDK [...]"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apache **Cordova** (was called `PhoneGap`) is an **open-source** **mobile** development framework. It allows you to use **standard** web technologies - `HTML5`, `CSS3`, and `JavaScript` for **`cross-platform`** development. Applications execute within **wrappers** targeted to each platform, and rely on standards-compliant `API` bindings to access each device's capabilities such as sensors, data, **network status**, etc.
[document reference `cordova`](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/overview/)

In your problem (Option 1):

```
navigator.onLine
```

...is **not** working because (on `android`) it is broken {the "raw" version, `Cordova` enabled `webview` is different}(as you have found out), you have to built your `WebView` App with the **`Cordova Framework`**. `Cordova` was developed **EXACTLY** to solve this problem. The GAP in `PhoneGap` is the gap between the "virtual machine", "sandbox" and access to the hardware, **AND** it's cross-platform.

Android Permissions:
app/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Cordova Permissions:
app/res/xml/config.xml

```
<feature name="NetworkStatus">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.networkinformation.NetworkManager" />
</feature>
```

## Quick Guide `Cordova` installation

### goto web page for installation instructions

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/

### goto web page and download nodejs for your system

https://nodejs.org/en/download/

### example file

```
node-v4.5.0-x86.msi
```

### run (install it)

```
success.
```

### on Windows:

```
C:\>npm install -g cordova
```

***And away you go!***

I have built your code into `cordova`, I'm getting there (hopefully, hard problem), here's some image's of what I  have so far [not in `WebView` exactly yet, {see the `navigator.userAgent` output in the second image}] (notice the event listener is working ;O), but not good enough:o( ).

[image: demo image offline]
[image: demo image online]

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome and Safari, if the browser is not able to connect to a local area network (LAN) or a router, it is offline; all other conditions return true. So while you can assume that the browser is offline when it returns a false value, you cannot assume that a true value necessarily means that the browser can access the internet. You could be getting false positives, such as in cases where the computer is running a virtualization software that has virtual ethernet adapters that are always "connected." Therefore, if you really want to determine the online status of the browser, you should develop additional means for checking. To learn more, see the HTML5 Rocks article, http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/workingoffthegrid/