# None of the plugins can be loaded in Cordova/PhoneGap Android hybrid mobile app. How to solve?

Tags: android, cordova, firebase, phonegap-plugins, onesignal

I have followed the instructions here to the dot. (https://documentation.onesignal.com/v3.0/docs/phonegap-sdk-setup)

My goal is to send Push Notifications from a server (Firebase or OneSignal) to my Android device which I am testing on Chrome browser or PhoneGap test app.

I have added the following code to my `onDeviceReady` function and it runs;

```
console.log("OneSignal is here!");
var notificationOpenedCallback = function(jsonData) {
  console.log('notificationOpenedCallback: ' + JSON.stringify(jsonData));
  alert("Received my notification");
};

// c02be63f-e777-4b99-8775-dec62efxxxxx is my APP ID
window.plugins.OneSignal
  .startInit("c02be63f-e777-4b99-8775-dec62efxxxxx") 
  .handleNotificationOpened(notificationOpenedCallback)
  .endInit();

window.plugins.OneSignal.setSubscription (true);

window.plugins.OneSignal.enableNotificationWhenActive(true);
```

However, after running, I get the following errors. Can someone please explain what this error means?

```
Error: exec proxy not found for :: StatusBar :: _ready
(index):365 OneSignal is here!
(index):365 Error: exec proxy not found for :: OneSignalPush :: setNotificationReceivedHandler
(index):365 Error: exec proxy not found for :: OneSignalPush :: setNotificationOpenedHandler
(index):365 Error: exec proxy not found for :: OneSignalPush :: init
(index):365 Error: exec proxy not found for :: OneSignalPush :: setSubscription
```

I have noticed the same error for every other new plugin I tried. This means something is wrong.

Here is my `config.xml`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.upen.testing" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
    <name>Testing</name>
    <description>
        A blank PhoneGap app.
    </description>
    <author email="support@phonegap.com" href="http://phonegap.com">
        PhoneGap Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <gap:plugin name="onesignal-cordova-plugin" source="npm" spec="^2.2.4" />
    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-7.1.1" />
    <preference name="android-build-tool" value="gradle" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="15" />
    <engine name="browser" spec="~5.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="~1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="onesignal-cordova-plugin" spec="~2.2.4" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="~2.3.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-fcm" spec="^2.1.2" />
    <engine name="android" spec="~6.3.0" />
</widget>
```

Comment: see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39066959/check-internet-connection-in-android-webview-cordova/39211383#39211383) a Quick Guide Cordova installation.

Comment: I've installed Cordova/PhoneGap/Node.js - everything is working. Except plugins loaded in a test project get this exec... error.

Comment: I think the problem is with <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="~2.3.0" />. Try downloading and using  <plugin  name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" version="1.1.0" />

Comment: Do you have the cordova.js linked in your index.html?

Comment: Yes, cordova.js is linked.

Comment: When you added the plugins, did they install without errors? Do you get any error in cli when building the app? You could try a fresh init of the app - remove node_modules, platforms, plugins and do a cordova prepare op

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the key

> which I am testing on Chrome browser or PhoneGap test app.

If you test on Chrome, the Cordova plugins don't work there

If you test on the Phonegap test app, the Phonegap developer app is a Cordova app, and it has been built with some Cordova plugins, but it doesn't include the onesignal plugin, so you can't use the plugin when you test there.

So, what you have to do is to compile and run your app directly in your phone (without Chrome or Phonegap app)

I don't use Phonegap, so I'm not sure about the exact command you need. You can try

`phonegap run android --device`

or

`phonegap cordova run android --device`

or

`cordova run android --device` (this might require to install the Cordova CLI `npm install -g cordova`)

You will need to install the Android SDK to make previous commands to work.