# How to compile android apk from cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, apk

I am trying to make a quick app for android. I have followed several tutorials on how to build an app using js/html/css (apache cordova). Could someone help me out with compiling the project into an APK file? I did not find any tutorials on how to do that.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47167769/hello-world-android-app-with-as-few-files-as-possible-no-ide-and-text-editor/47251607#47251607) answer should help you. [Quick Cordova install guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39066959/check-internet-connection-in-android-webview-cordova/39211383#39211383)

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't. Even more things to download.